# Reading complex json data without iteration

Tags: json, nested

I am working with some data and often the data is nested and i am required to perform some CRUD operations based on the structure of the data i have. For instance i have this json structure

```
{
    "_id": "KnNLkJEhrDsvWedLu",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2016-10-13T11:24:13.843Z"
    },
    "services": {
        "password": {
            "bcrypt": "$2a$30$1/cniPwPNCuwZ/MQDPQkLej..cAATkoGX.qD1TS4iHgf/pwZYE.j."
        },
        "email": {
            "verificationTokens": [
                {
                    "token": "qxe_T9IS7jW7gntpK0Q7UQ35RJ9jO9m2lclnokO3z87",
                    "address": "drwho@gmail.com",
                    "when": {
                        "$date": "2016-10-13T11:24:14.428Z"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "resume": {
            "loginTokens": []
        }
    },
    "username": "doctorwho",
    "emails": [
        {
            "address": "drwho@gmail.com",
            "verified": false
        }
    ],
    "persodata": {
        "lastlogin": {
            "$date": "2016-10-13T11:29:36.816Z"
        },
        "fname": "Doctor",
        "lname": "Who",
        "mobile": "+4480000000",
        "identity": "1",
        "email": "drwho@gmail.com",
        "gender": null
    }
}
```

I have several data sets with such complex structure. I need to read the data, edit and also delete. Before i get to iteration, i was wondering how i can read the data without iteration then iterate when i absolutely have to.

What are the rules i should keep in mind when reading such complex json structures to enable me read any complex structure i come across?.

I am currently using javascript but i am looking for rules that apply in other languages as well.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing Json in JavaScript should be easy. http://www.json.org/js.html.
"Since JSON is a proper subset of JavaScript, the compiler will correctly parse the text and produce an object structure". Just follow the examples on that page.

If you want to use another language, in Java you could use Jackson or Gson to map those json strings to objects. Then using them becomes easy. Both libraries are annotation based, and wouldn't be difficult to implement.

Comment: Cool, i am going to check out Jackson and Gson.I like gson goals already https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Goals-for-Gson

Comment: which solution did you go with?